# Is there any way to speed up cURL

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I was wondering whether there's any way to speed up a cURL request like this via PHP.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.randomsite.com/path');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36');
$html = trim(curl_exec($ch));

echo $html;

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I'm looping this a few hundred times and it's taking pretty long, therefore I'd like to know if there's any way to speed up this process.

Comment: Obvious question, why are you looping this a few hundred times? Are you downloading several pages? What kind of data does the page have? Does the data have a lifetime? Meaning how long is the data valid?

Comment: I am downloading several pages, not the same one a hundred times and the page is fully consisting of HTML code.

Comment: True HTML or generated HTML? Can you cache the data?

Comment: it's true html.

Comment: In that case it's just a matter of downloading them once and saving them as txt files on your own webserver. Then just use file_get_contents on the local txt file and you will probably save about one second per page.

Comment: but is there any way speeding it up while using curl every time?

Comment: Not that I know of, there is something called multicurl if I recall correct. Never used it though. But why do you want to download the same date every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, first thing you can do, is to enable compression, if the content you're fetching benefits from compression (this excludes jpg/png/gif/anything pre-compressed, but stuff like html/css/javascript/xml benefits greatly from transfer compression) - set `CURLOPT_ENCODING` to emptystring to have curl take care of transfer compression automatically.

`I'm looping this a few hundred times and it's taking pretty long` - unless you cannot for some reason fetch them concurrently, just use the curl_multi api, then you can fetch hundreds of them simultaneously, should be *significantly* faster than using the curl_exec method (which can only fetch them serially)